# How to create different environment for react-native application

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native to build android app. I need to define different mode for developer, tester, production. Different mode will use different configuration files or variables. How can I achieve this in react-native application?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an option flag to the bundler command like so:

## Production bundle

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

## Dev/Test mode enabled

```
react-native bundle --dev true --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

Comment: You can read about this in numerous source files of react itself.
They set the `__DEV__` flag on development builds.

Comment: How to set these flags on `react-native run-android` command line? Since I am using this command to run the app on simulator and need to setup some flags.